# memory error in python on mac

Tags: python, dictionary

I have around 10000 file, containing a big amount of data.

Im trying to build a python dict for all the files, and for some data within each file.

what i did is something like that:

```
results = {}
for bfile in os.listdir(files_dir):
      fname, ext = os.path.splitext(bfile)

      fhandle = open(os.path.join(files_dir,bfile), 'r' )
      if not results.has_key(fname):
                results[fname] = {}
      for line in fhandle:
          line = line.split("\t")


          if not results[fname].has_key(line[0]):
                 results[fname][line[0]] = {}

          if not results[fname][line[0]].has_key(line[1]):
                 results[fname][line[0]][line[1]] = {}
```

It should have been as a trivial task but i'm getting this error :

```
  File "script.py", line 409, in <module>
    file_handle()
  File "script.py", line 247, in file_handle
    results[fname][line[0]][line[1]] = {}
MemoryError
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 18, in <module>
    import problem_report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 14, in <module>
    import zlib, base64, time, sys, gzip, struct, os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 10, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _io
MemoryError

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 409, in <module>
    file_handle()
  File "script.py", line 247, in file_handle
    results[fname][line[0]][line[1]] = {}
MemoryError
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: How much physical memory do you have, and how big are the files you're dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are never closing a file after you are done with it. This *might* be the problem, so try the following:

```
with open(os.path.join(files_dir, bfile), 'r') as fhandle: 
    if not results.has_key(fname):
        results[fname] = {}
    for line in fhandle:
        line = line.split("\t")

        if not results[fname].has_key(line[0]):
            results[fname][line[0]] = {}

        if not results[fname][line[0]].has_key(line[1]):
            results[fname][line[0]][line[1]] = {}
```